# Json data display - css, html

Tags: php, css, json

Welcome! I have a question. Today i tried to get json api from URL and i have this code:

```
 <?php
$url = "http://services.faa.gov/airport/status/LAX?format=json";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
if(!$json) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
print_r(json_decode($json));
?>
```

In return in html i have something like this:

```
 stdClass Object ( [delay] => false [IATA] => LAX [state] => California [name] => Los Angeles International [weather] => stdClass Object ( [visibility] => 10 [weather] => Overcast [meta] => stdClass Object ( [credit] => NOAA's National Weather Service [updated] => 9:53 PM Local [url] => http://weather.gov/ ) [temp] => 54.0 F (12.2 C) [wind] => East at 12.7mph ) [ICAO] => KLAX [city] => Los Angeles [status] => stdClass Object ( [reason] => No known delays for this airport. [closureBegin] => [endTime] => [minDelay] => [avgDelay] => [maxDelay] => [closureEnd] => [trend] => [type] => ) )
```

And now my question is how to style it in css and display it nice not in this way like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

It will return std class object, you can access its values like:

```
$obj->name;
$obj->delay;
```

and so on. Now you can use your own html & css to **display it nice**